# Regex for trailing and leading

Tags: javascript, regex

This might seem simple, but I have no knowledge in regex whatsoever. I need a regex that allows numbers, letters, hyphens and underscores only.. anything else is not allowed, so far I have:

```
/^[a-zA-Z\d]+$/
```

This matches numbers and letters but not hypens or underscores.

I don't want it to match any special characters within the string

Does anyone understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the language, BTW? JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say

> a regex that allows numbers, letters, hyphens and underscores only

So, use

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$
```

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/aG9wF1/1).

**Explanation**:

- `^` - Start of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*` - Character class matching lowercase (`a-z`) and uppercase (`A-Z`) letters, numbers (`0-9`), an underscore (`_`), and a hyphen (`-`). Note the hyphen is at the end, and thus does not have to be escaped. `+` means *1 or more occurrences*. If you allow an empty string, use `*` instead.
- `$` - End of string